# common issue : ssh: connect to host 10.0.2.15 port 22: Connection refused

Tags: server, virtualbox, ssh

I am using VirtualBox on Windows 10 (host) to create two virtual machines (`Guest DT` and `Guest S`). Can I SSH from `Guest DT` to the `Guest S`?

- `Guest DT` is Ubuntu **Desktop** 18.04.
- `Guest S` is running Ubuntu **Server** 18.04.
- [VirtualBox Terminology](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#virtintro)

I am inexperienced with SSH. I have googled and read answers to the 'similar questions' on this site.

#### Error

On `Guest DT`, I do this:

```
$ ssh test@10.0.2.15
ssh: connect to host 10.0.2.15 port 22: Connection refused
```

**Note:**

- I can successfully ping 10.0.2.15
- `test` is my username on the `Guest S`.

### Environment Setup

On `Guest DT`:

```
$ ssh-keygen
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
ssh-rsa <a very long key> neil@neil-VirtualBox
```

On `Guest S`:

```
$ mkdir ~/.ssh
$ chmod 700 ~/.ssh
$ touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
$ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
$ echo "ssh-rsa <a very long key> neil@neil-VirtualBox" > ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
$ /etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

On `Guest S`:

```
test@server01:~$ service sshd status

ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-06-15 02:05:04 UTC; 1h 16min ago
  Process: 903 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 906 (sshd)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 2317)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
           └─906 /usr/sbin/sshd -D

Jun 15 02:05:04 server01 systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Jun 15 02:05:04 server01 sshd[906]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Jun 15 02:05:04 server01 sshd[906]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Jun 15 02:05:04 server01 systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.


$ sudo ufw status
[sudo] password for test: 
Status: inactive


/etc/ssh/sshd_config  contains :
#PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

Comment: Please run `sudo ufw status`, and [edit] your question to add the output from that command.

Comment: make sure `PubkeyAuthentication` is set to `yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Comment: Are the VM's networks configured as "NAT" or "NAT Network"?

Comment: Um, `#PubkeyAuthentication yes` is commented out, you need to remove the hash. I'd have tested with a simple password first. Presumably the ssh traffic passes through the host and could be blocked by its firewall?

Comment: I have now left
PubkeyAuthentication yes
uncommented.

I had previously left it as a comment, because I read this in the top of the file : 

    # The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
    # OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
    # possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
    # default value.

I had therefore thought (perhaps wrongly) that PubkeyAuthentication yes
was the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the default networking setup for VirtualBox guest is `NAT` and is not really intended to achieve this type of networking communication; but based on old posts may be possible by *forwarding* a non-system port to a Guest port and using the default *loopback IP address* to reach the Guest. 10.0.2.2 is default loopback.

#### Setup Networking

However, the easiest is to ensure you choose the correct networking for each of the Guests. Shutdown you guest machines, then in VirtualBox edit the [Networking mode appropriate for your needs (note grid)](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes).

[image: Virtualbox steps to change networking]

### Using Default NAT Network

Using NAT, VirtualBox uses a special IP 10.0.2.2 as a loopback (at least I think this is still true). Therefore ports forwarded from loopback are available to all guests.  I think you should be able to take advantage of this. To communicate using a NAT network, will require one of the following:

- Using VBoxManage, setup NAT Forwarding of a [non-system port (1024–65535)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Dynamic,_private_or_ephemeral_ports) to a lower [system port (< 1024)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports).

  1. In this case forward something like port 2222, to port 22 (default for SSH). This also assumes we'll use `Guest S` IP address of `10.0.2.15`, per the question.
  2. Configure port forwarding on the Virtualbox Host, run:

     VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --natpf1 "guestssh,tcp,,2222,,22"

     *All TCP traffic arriving on port 2222 on any host interface will be forwarded to port 22 in the guest. The protocol name tcp is a mandatory attribute defining which protocol should be used for forwarding (udp could also be used). The name guestssh is purely descriptive and will be auto-generated if omitted. The number after --natpf denotes the network card, like in other parts of VBoxManage.*
  3. Check the added rule:

     VBoxManage showvminfo myserver | grep 'Rule'
  4. Connect to `Guest Server` via host loopback mapping and port-forwarding for `Guest S`

     neil@neil-VirtualBox$ ssh -p 2222 test@10.0.2.2
- Alternative: change (*Guest S*) [/etc/sshd_config](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config) to listen on a
  [non-system port (> 1024)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Dynamic,_private_or_ephemeral_ports). Then reload ssh.

Comment: How do I love thee?  
Let me count the ways

Comment: This formatting is driving me nuts. My previous comment is taken straight out of the help on how to make a line break and it isn't working for me. I have 2 spaces after 'How do I love thee? ' but 'Let me count the ways' is not on a new line.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  
    My SSH is working.
    
    I have one concern.
    
    At one point in the process I got this message :  
    
    The authenticity of host '[10.0.2.2]:2222 ([10.0.2.2]:2222)' can't be established.
    ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:kG7aJHOmo+ej8JF8L7iQ924NngwZv84ndtvCsEdBP/M.
    Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
    
    I answered 'yes' and continued, but I suspect I should really have answered 'no', then tried to resolve the issue.
    
    I will post what I did in a further comment.
    It made this comment too long to post.

Comment: When in doubt... esp when it comes to connecting to other servers (ssh/http/https/etc) search for an answer. Finding info has never been easier.  But you might consider reading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3664010  .... that said... and generally speaking connecting to resources on your own local network is pretty darn safe.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove all ECDSA fingerprint keys (probably SHA256) contained within known-hosts directory.

1. Run `vi ~/.ssh/known_hosts`
2. Delete all keys associated with subject IP-address within the known_hosts file.
3. Enter "Esc"-key then "Shift"-key + ":" + "x"